# Failed to add install user to %2% group

Tags: oracle18c

Hello I have Windows 10 pro.
I keep getting one and the same error all the time, I tried to make a user, tried with Virtual user and with Build-in account and always get the same error.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What successfully worked for me is Just Make the **Computer Name** and **User Name** different(I changed my computer name).Then reinstall!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when installing 19c, what worked for me was to sign in to Windows 10 as Administrator(though my user account was in Administrators group) and install it under this account.

Answer (score 0):

try to login with different user and from there run it as administrator

Answer (score 0):

> VBT = VBT (it is not possible.) Failed to add **VBT\VBT** install user to %2% group

> VBT != VBTAS (Yes)

VBT user name image:
[image: VBT user name image]

VBTAS account name image:
[image: VBTAS account name image]